# Javax-servlet-api 4.0.1 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionIdListener Error

Tags: java, spring, servlets

I'm getting a

```
SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionIdListener
```

error when running my project within Eclipse. In the list of maven dependencies, `javax.servlet-api-4.0.1` is present, and contains the `HttpSessionIdListener` class.

I'm not sure how to even begin troubleshooting this. Other posts on the same topic suggest cleaning the project, and reinstalling the Tomcat server etc, all of which I've done, but to no success.

Why can't the HttpSessionIdListener class be found?

Dependencies are (in two files - parent and module..):

Parent:

```
<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vmlens</groupId>
                <artifactId>concurrent-junit</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>net.jodah</groupId>
                <artifactId>concurrentunit</artifactId>
                <version>0.4.3</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.17</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.19</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.25</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.19</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency> 
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> 
                <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId> 
                <version>${spring.framework.version}</version> 
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-acl</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.jms-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
                <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
                <version>1.7</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
                <artifactId>velocity-tools</artifactId>
                <version>2.0</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <!-- Causes issues with hibernate, remove as this is the old version -->
                        <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
                        <groupId>antlr</groupId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.7</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
                <version>4.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                <version>1.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
                <version>1.4</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
                <version>1.10</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-net</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-net</artifactId>
                <version>3.6</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
                <version>1.9.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
                <artifactId>xmlgraphics-commons</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
                <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
                <version>1.3</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
                <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
                <version>${javassist.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
                <artifactId>fop</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <artifactId>avalon-framework-api</artifactId>
                        <groupId>org.apache.avalon.framework</groupId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <artifactId>avalon-framework-impl</artifactId>
                        <groupId>org.apache.avalon.framework</groupId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>pdfbox</groupId>
                <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
                <version>0.7.3</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.avalon.framework</groupId>
                <artifactId>avalon-framework-api</artifactId>
                <version>4.3.1</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.fontbox</groupId>
                <artifactId>fontbox</artifactId>
                <version>0.1.0</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.beanshell</groupId>
                <artifactId>bsh</artifactId>
                <version>2.0b5</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
                <artifactId>el-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun.el</groupId>
                <artifactId>el-ri</artifactId>
                <version>1.0</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>net.objectlab.kit</groupId>
                <artifactId>datecalc-common</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.1</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>net.objectlab.kit</groupId>
                <artifactId>datecalc-jdk8</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.1</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
                <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
                <version>2.9.3</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
                <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.2</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
                        <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
                <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
                <version>3.11</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.ant</groupId>
                <artifactId>ant</artifactId>
                <version>1.9.6</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
                <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.3</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
                <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
                <version>1.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.dom4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.3</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
                <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.15</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
                <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
                <version>4.1</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.jgoodies</groupId>
                <artifactId>forms</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.netty</groupId>
                <artifactId>netty</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.5.Final</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.javaee</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-jms-api</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.0.GA</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>net.sf.json-lib</groupId>
                <artifactId>json-lib</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>net.sf.ezmorph</groupId>
                <artifactId>ezmorph</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.6</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-jci-core</artifactId>
                <version>1.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-jci-fam</artifactId>
                <version>1.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty</artifactId>
                <version>6.1.18</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-util</artifactId>
                <version>6.1.18</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.1</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
                <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.1</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>xerces</groupId>
                <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
                <version>2.11.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>jaxen</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxen</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.6</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>xerces</groupId>
                        <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.mockftpserver</groupId>
                <artifactId>MockFtpServer</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>asm</groupId>
                <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.amazonservices</groupId>
                <artifactId>mwsclient</artifactId>
                <version>1.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.amazonservices</groupId>
                <artifactId>subscription-api</artifactId>
                <version>1.0-2013-09-26</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
                <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-core</artifactId>
                <version>1.11.526</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
                <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
                <version>1.11.526</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
                <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-sqs</artifactId>
                <version>1.11.526</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
                <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-sns</artifactId>
                <version>1.11.526</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.esotericsoftware</groupId>
                <artifactId>kryo-shaded</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
                <artifactId>lucene-core</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
                <artifactId>lucene-analyzers</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>stax</groupId>
                <artifactId>stax-api</artifactId>
                <version>1.0</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
                <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
                <version>3.11</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
                <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
                <version>3.11</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
                <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
                <version>2.9.8</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
                <version>2.9.8</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                <version>2.9.8</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
                <version>2.9.8</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.3</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
                <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.01</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
                <artifactId>xml-apis-ext</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.04</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>xom</groupId>
                <artifactId>xom</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.5</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>oro</groupId>
                <artifactId>oro</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.8</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
                <version>1.2_15</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
                <version>1.2_15</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun.facelets</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsf-facelets</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.14</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.shale</groupId>
                <artifactId>shale-test</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.5</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.tomahawk</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomahawk12</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.14</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
                <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
                <version>0.9.5.5</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
                <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.objenesis</groupId>
                <artifactId>objenesis</artifactId>
                <version>1.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
                <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.openfaces</groupId>
                <artifactId>openfaces</artifactId>
                <version>2.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
                <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
                <version>1.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>net.sf.barcode4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>barcode4j</artifactId>
                <version>2.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
                <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
                <version>2.6.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
                <version>26.0-jre</version>
                <scope>compile</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springmodules</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-modules-jakarta-commons</artifactId>
                <version>0.8a</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId> 
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-configuration</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-configuration</artifactId>
                <version>1.6</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.github.spullara.mustache.java</groupId>
                <artifactId>compiler</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.17</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
                <version>0.1.55</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
                <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
                <version>4.4.10</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vdurmont</groupId>
                <artifactId>emoji-java</artifactId>
                <version>5.1.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                <version>1.18.10</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
                <artifactId>keycloak-spring-security-adapter</artifactId>
                <version>9.0.3</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

Module:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.blank</groupId>
        <artifactId>shop</artifactId>
        <version>16.29</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>shop-webcustomer</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>shop-webcustomer project</name>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jmock</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmock-junit4</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jmock</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmock-legacy</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.dom4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.jms-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
            <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
            <artifactId>el-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>oro</groupId>
            <artifactId>oro</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.facelets</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-facelets</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.shale</groupId>
            <artifactId>shale-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.tomahawk</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomahawk12</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
            <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.beanshell</groupId>
            <artifactId>bsh</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.objenesis</groupId>
            <artifactId>objenesis</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>asm</groupId>
            <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
            <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>xml-apis-ext</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openfaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>openfaces</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
            <artifactId>lucene-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
            <artifactId>lucene-analyzers</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.json-lib</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-lib</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.ezmorph</groupId>
            <artifactId>ezmorph</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>activemq-client</artifactId>
            <version>5.12.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jaxen</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxen</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.19</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>19.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

RESOLVED: Figured out that I was trying to use Tomcat 7 with Servlet 4.0.1, which doesn't work. (tomcat 7 requires Servlet 3.0.x)

Comment: Show your dependencies.

Comment: edited to add dependencies

Answer (score 0):

RESOLVED: Figured out that I was trying to use Tomcat 7 with Servlet 4.0.1, which doesn't work. (Tomcat 7 requires Servlet 3.0.x).

Upgrading to Tomcat 9 seemed to do the job